# Load XML file add Values and Save

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file that we are using systemlink for in AS400.  I have the working XML file and if I just do a load document on the button click it writes to the database the hard coded values.  However, I would like to patch values from textboxes in.  Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE System-Link SYSTEM 'SystemLinkRequest.dtd'>
      <System-Link>
<Login userId='' password='' maxIdle='900000'
   properties='com.pjx.cas.domain.EnvironmentId=RN,
           com.pjx.cas.domain.SystemName=,
           com.pjx.cas.user.LanguageId=en'/>

<Request sessionHandle='*current' workHandle='*new'
   broker='EJB' maxIdle='1000'>

<Create name='newObject_ITItemLocation_Default' domainClass='EXT0149' retainResult='false'>
  <ApplyTemplate clientClass='EXT0149'>
    <![CDATA[Asset]]>
  </ApplyTemplate>
  <DomainEntity>
    <Property path='ponum'>
      <Value><![CDATA[P21851]]></Value>
    </Property>
    <Property path='itmnbr'>
      <Value><![CDATA[909520]]></Value>
    </Property>
    <Property path='itmcls'>
      <Value><![CDATA[1]]></Value>
    </Property>
    <Property path='itmloc'>
      <Value><![CDATA[1]]></Value>
    </Property>
    <Property path='srnum'>
      <Value><![CDATA[]]></Value>
    </Property>
  </DomainEntity>
</Create>
```

And here is my C#:

```
enterXmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load(Server.MapPath("~/addNew.xml"));
XmlElement po = document.GetElementById("ponum");
po.Value = poTextBox.Text;
document.Save(Server.MapPath("~/addNew.xml"));
```

Every time I try and run it I get an object not found so I'm guessing it can't find the ponum field. I'd like to patch the poTextBox.Text in where it is currently P21851. Any suggestions like I said if I just do the document.Load on button click it writes to the DB just fine, I just want to patch my values in.

Comment: Is that the whole XML? As it stands its not valid (no root) - `ponum` is not an ID.

Comment: I suppose that the given XML snippet is not complete (as @AlexK. suggested), anyway with a well-formatted XML, I suggest that you use "document.SelectNodes(<input XPATH here>)" to find the correct node

Comment: You need to somehow tell the XmlDocument (with the help of a DTD perhaps) that the "path" attribute is the element ID.

Comment: This is the entire XML block that I got back from Powerlink/System Link.. I will try your idea @Oxald

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use serialization for converting the xml into an object so you can do what ever you want? Do you have the xsd?

Answer (score 0):

Decided to take a different approach and just put it into a string and did an HttpWebRequest so that I could just patch in my values into my string.  Thanks for the answers one day I'll mess with how to make that work in an XML document.

```
string asset = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>" + "<!DOCTYPE System-Link SYSTEM 'SystemLinkRequest.dtd'>" + "<System-Link>" + "<Login userId='' password='' maxIdle='900000' properties='com.pjx.cas.domain.EnvironmentId=RN, com.pjx.cas.domain.SystemName=,com.pjx.cas.user.LanguageId=en'/>" + "<Request sessionHandle='*current' workHandle='*new' broker='EJB' maxIdle='1000'>" + "<Create name='newObject_ITItemLocation_Default' domainClass='EXT0149' retainResult='false'>" + "<ApplyTemplate clientClass='EXT0149'>" + "<![CDATA[Asset]]>" + "</ApplyTemplate>" + "<DomainEntity>" + "<Property path='ponum'><Value><![CDATA[" + poTextBox.Text + "]]></Value></Property>" + "<Property path='itmnbr'><Value><![CDATA[" + itemNoTextBox.Text + "]]></Value></Property>" + "<Property path='itmcls'><Value><![CDATA[" + classDropDown.SelectedValue +"]]></Value></Property>" + "<Property path='itmloc'><Value><![CDATA[" + locationDropDown.SelectedValue + "]]></Value></Property>" + "<Property path='srnum'><Value><![CDATA["+ serialTextBox.Text +"]]></Value></Property>" + "</DomainEntity>" + "</Create>" + "</Request>" + "</System-Link>";

String wRequestString = "SystemLinkRequest=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(asset);
```